# How to enable sslv3 in openssl for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls

I am researching the attacks against TLS as a part of my Masters topic. But as I am using the ubuntu 16.04 the ssl3 in OpenSSL is permanently disabled here.

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -ssl3
```

the output shows this error:

```
139852446676632:error:140A90C4:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_new:null ssl method passed:ssl_lib.c:1878:
```

How can I enable sslv3 for openssl? I have to test downgrade attack like SSLstrip or poddle against my local server.

Comment: It's permanently disabled, read here... http://askubuntu.com/questions/774760/openssl-s-client-connect-gmail-com443-ssl3-not-working  - you'll need to compile openssl from source